# Kafka: IS it possible to have conumer and Publisher on Same kafka client object?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Can I have a kafka consumer and publisher on same kafka client connetion.

```
kafka_conn = KafkaClient(**conf.KAFKA_SERVER)
consumer = KafkaConsumer(kafka_conn, *conf.DATA_TOPIC, **conf.KAFKA_CONSUMER_CONF)
producer = KafkaProducer(kafka_conn)
```

some thing like this.

Thanks in advance.